# SQL remove duplicates from query results

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

This is my SQL :

```
 SELECT * FROM unity_database.unit_uptime_daily
        inner join unity_database.units on unity_database.units.id = unity_database.unit_uptime_daily.unit_id
        where unity_database.units.location_id = 1
```

Below is a screenshot of the first part of the results :
[image]

I am trying to only show one result for each unit_id that has the latest date so in this example the unit with the unit_id of 30 should only be shown once, and it should be the bottom row.

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL workbench

Comment: So are you using MySQL?

Comment: Yeah i'm using MYSQL, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a MySQL solution you can consider:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.unit_id, t1.uptime, t1.total_update, t2.timestamp
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM unity_database.unit_uptime_daily ud1 INNER JOIN unity_database.units ud2
        ON ud2.id = ud1.unit_id
    WHERE ud2.location_id = 1
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ud1.unit_id, MAX(ud1.timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM unity_database.unit_uptime_daily ud1 INNER JOIN unity_database.units ud2
        ON ud2.id = ud1.unit_id
    WHERE ud2.location_id = 1
    GROUP BY ud1.unit_id
) t2
ON t1.unit_id = t2.unit_id AND t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
```

Comment: I get a duplicate column name ID on this, i'm sorry if im being an idiot i haven't worked much with MYSQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, since I don't have your database in front of me there is not much I can do.  I would suggest testing each of the two subqueries separately, to see what you get.  Then piece them together once you have solved the duplicate column problem (which I can't see based on what you told us).

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH X AS
(
SELECT * 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Unit_Id ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) rn
FROM unity_database.unit_uptime_daily
inner join unity_database.units 
on unity_database.units.id = unity_database.unit_uptime_daily.unit_id
where unity_database.units.location_id = 1
)
SELECT * FROM X Where rn = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Unit_Id ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) rn
    FROM unity_database.unit_uptime_daily
    inner join unity_database.units 
    on unity_database.units.id = unity_database.unit_uptime_daily.unit_id
    where unity_database.units.location_id = 1
     )A
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: actually i was making the same answer @M.Ali

Comment: None of these work, maybe its because i'm using SQLWorkbench?

Comment: Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION ROW_NUMBER does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Please if this answer will give you the results you're expecting:

```
 SELECT MAX(id) AS ID, unit_id, uptime, total_update, MAX(timestamp) as timesstamp FROM unity_database.unit_uptime_daily
    inner join unity_database.units on unity_database.units.id = unity_database.unit_uptime_daily.unit_id
 where unity_database.units.location_id = 1
 GROUP BY unit_id, uptime, total_update
```

PS: I didn't test but I'm positive it will work